# Make a button or menu's caption different from the Action it is linked to?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

When a button or a menu item is linked to an `Action`, its caption is changed to the one of the `Action`. How can this feature be overriden?

Comment: 1) Set control's caption after linking it to the action or 2) Patch LCL sources.

Comment: @Abelisto Whenever I set the caption it gets reverted

Comment: It should not, here set the caption after assigning the action works. Is the action assigned at design time ? If so then check that you set the caption after the lfm streaming is done. Also, is there any kind of idle timer that would re-assign the action during the run-time ?